# Variable name problem with VSCode autocomplete in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm encountering an issue with autocomplete in vscode with javascript files.

As you can see in the picture, autocomplete is not suggesting variables name when fired the first time (in this case the variable `simplify`).

The complete list of possible suggestions, also with the variable names, is showed when I backspace the string.

I don't know if it could be evaluated as a bug or a wrong configuration.

Do you have any advice?

[image: Javascript autocomplete problem with variable names]

Comment: in my setup `simplify` is the first in the suggestion list even when typing `s`, the snippets are way down the list, with `sim` the `settimeout` snippet is in the first 5 in the list

Comment: Like @rioV8. I also get `simplify` as the first suggestion

Comment: do you have a setting that puts the snippets at the top of the suggestion list